# AlarmManager doesn't work at api lvl < 11

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentservice

Here is [link](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks) of the guide of how to use `AlarmManager` with `BroadcastReceiver` and `IntentService`. It works pretty good on `>= API 11`, but it doesn't work at lower API (was tested on API10). I have been read a lot of documentations at the `dev.android` but have no result. `Receiver` doesn't call `onReceive` method and doesn't create new process. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works pretty good on >= API 11

No, it does not, because whoever wrote that explanation has not been paying attention since 2009.

> it doesn't works at lower API (was tested on API10)

It should work as well on API Level 10 as it does on API Level 11+. If the device is asleep at the time of the alarm, your `Service` may or may not run.

To use `_WAKEUP`-style alarms, [use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Also, remove the `android:process` attribute suggested by that "guide", as that will interfere with the use of either `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or `WakefulIntentService`.